# Do I need to check null on both sides of an OR condition?

Tags: java, string, null, is-empty

Consider member variable:

```
String foo;
```

I only want to call `setFoo` if `foo` has not previously been set or currently is empty.

For this purpose, I am not sure if this is sufficient:

```
if(foo==null || foo.isEmpty()) {

  setFoo(foo);

}
```

Or is it safer to also check for null on the other side of the OR condition:

```
if(foo==null || (foo!=null && foo.isEmpty())) {

  setFoo(foo);

}
```

Comment: It wud have been easier, faster and more enlightening to have checked? :-)

Answer (score 12):

`if(foo==null || foo.isEmpty())` is sufficient.

In a Logical OR condition, Java will only evaluate the second part if the first part is false.

Comment: In a *logical* OR expression.  In *bitwise* OR, they are both evaluated.

Comment: On a side note if u r going to have several such checks it is always a good idea to extract this into a method.. Something on the lines of StringUtils..

Answer (score 4):

No, the first snippet is fine.

In Java (and in many similar languages like C or C++), the logical operators `&&` and `||` perform *short-circuit evaluation*.  In the case of `||`, if the left-hand operand is `true`, then the right-hand operand won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow

Operators like `||`, `&&` in Java are **short-circuit operator**, 
the second part of expression will only be checked when first part are not enough to determine the value

so, `if(foo==null || foo.isEmpty())` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (foo == null || foo.isEmpty()) setFoo(foo);
```

Works fine. In this case, if `foo` is null, `setFoo(foo)` will be called. If `foo` isn't null, and `foo` is empty, `setFoo(foo)` will also be called.

Answer (score 0):

I find it more elegant to use `StringUtils.isBlank(foo)` (from apache commons-lang), so you don't need the || at all.

Comment: But you have to have apache commons on the class path…

Comment: Yes, obviously. So put it there, learn how to use it and write beautiful code :).